# How is concurrency managed in output binding for Cosmos DB in azure function?

Tags: database, azure, concurrency, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a function app and it has 2 functions in it, *Function1* which is an HTTPTrigger function and runs when an HTTP call is hit on it, it then sends the payload to service bus and completes its execution.

Another function *Function2* runs when something is published in the service bus queue and it then checks the corresponding data in the CosmosDB and if it is already present then it updates some keys in it otherwise, it creates a new document in the database.

The problem I am facing is that if 2 requests are made on the HTTPTrigger function then only one of those are executed, I want to check if there is a way I can look for concurrency in the CosmosDB operation.

The update operation on cosmosDB is through the output binding.

`context.bindings.outputDocument = updatedDocument`

Answer (score 0):

Output binding just performs an Upsert operation. If you Upsert the same document (same id and partition key value) twice, it's still a single document (first Upsert creates the document, second Upsert updates it).

Concurrency is based on the Triggers and how they execute, in your case, it depends on the HTTP Trigger and how it handles concurrent requests. Either the Upserts are sequential or concurrent, but from the Output Binding perspective it doesn't matter, each is an independent Upsert call.

Comment: *@Matias Quaranta* So, Is there a way I can manage the upsert operation in Function2, I have checked and in some cases the data is not consistent as when both the function executes, they get the same data and they both makes same updation. For example I have a key in DB document *clicks*, after 2 request it incremented only once. Can you please guide how can I manage this case. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, the interfaces exposed by Azure Function bindings (all bindings expose the same interface) do not allow for customization of the Upsert operation